# Most efficient way to remove object from inside of an iterating ArrayList

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I'm trying to remove an object from an iterating ArrayList but cannot do so from inside of the loop, here is what I have at the moment

```
        for(Pearl pearl : this.pearls){
            pearl.onDraw(canvas);

            if(fish.isCollide(pearl)){
                this.pearls.remove(pearl);
            }
        }
```

The above code does not work if the ArrayList is larger than 1.

I was thinking of changing the code to something such as the following but would prefer to know if there is a simpler way.

```
       List<Pearl> pearls_delete = new ArrayList<Pearl>();


       for(Pearl pearl : this.pearls){
            pearl.onDraw(canvas);

            if(fish.isCollide(pearl)){
                pearls_delete.add(pearl);
            }
        }

        this.pearls.removeAll(pearls_delete);
```

Comment: Your solution is common one. There is no easier solution for this.

Comment: @libik That is not correct. See my solution with `Iterator` below

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use an `Iterator`

```
Iterator<Pearl> iter = this.pearls.iterator();
while ( iter.hasNext() ) {
   Pearl pearl = iter.next();
   // logic
   iter.remove();
}
```

or simply

```
for (Iterator<Pearl> iter = pearls.iterator(); iter.hasNext();) {
   Pearl pearl = iter.next();
   // logic
   iter.remove();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it's very pretty code